# Case Else loop back to Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which use Select Case to pick an email template based on the value of a cell.

However, on occassion, the cell which is being checked in blank. Is it possible that I can change the cell which is being checked e.g. (row + 1) in the Case Else and then loop back to the start of the Select Case, e.g.:

```
CellToCheck = .Cell(1, 1)

Select Case CellToCheck

Case = 1
Email = "blah blah 1"

Case = 2
Email = "blah blah 2"

Case = 3
Email = "blah blah 3"

Case Else
CellToCheck = Cell(2,1)
'Loop back to "Select Case CellToCheck
```

I thought about including this in a Do While loop, but I wouldn't know how to exit the loop if Case Else isn't called.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should use a loop block or jump statement (not recommended). To exit the `Do` loop, simple use `Exit Do`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the 2 cells you check?  If so, try a conditional at the beginning.

```
Function EmailCheck()

    Dim Email As String
    Dim CellToCheck As Integer

    CellToCheck = Cells(1, 1).Value
    If Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then CellToCheck = Cells(2, 1).Value

    Select Case CellToCheck

    Case Is = 1
    Email = "blah blah 1"

    Case Is = 2
    Email = "blah blah 2"

    Case Is = 3
    Email = "blah blah 3"

    Case Else
    MsgBox "Check Range Values"
    Exit Function

    End Select

    MsgBox Email

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
   CellToCheck = .Cell(1, 1)
   email = ""

   Do While email = ""
      Select Case CellToCheck
         Case Is = 1
            email = "blah blah 1"

         Case Is = 2
            email = "blah blah 2"

         Case Is = 3
            email = "blah blah 3"

         Case Else
            CellToCheck = Cell(2, 1)
      End Select
   Loop
```